# Node.js accessing files from inside modules

Tags: node.js

I am trying to access a file from inside a module. I have given the file location inside module as below.My module folder is called helper.

__dirname + "/../public/lib/objects"

500 Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/sushmitsarmah/projects/app/helpers/public/lib/objects'

It gives me an error with location being helper/public/lib/objects. I tried this next:

__dirname + "/../../public/lib/objects". This also gives me an error.

How should I access the public folder? In the directory structure helper and public are in the same level.

folder structure:

```
app
 --helpers
     --getData.js
 --public
     --lib
       --objects
 --views
 --app.js
```

In app.js I call:
    var getdata = require('./helpers/getdata').getData;

From inside getData.js I want to access the objects folder.

Thanks

Comment: provide system paths of both current and target include file in your question

Answer (score 2):

Note that `__dirname` points the directory that the currently executing script resides in. So in our case it is the directory where script is located. So the current working directory will always point to the folder of app.js where as the `__dirname` will change according to the file which is in execution.

So your path should be

```
__dirname + "/public/lib/objects" //from app.js
```

note:

In the folder structure updated above, when you are in `getData.js`, the value of `__dirname` will be "/rootpath/app/helpers". To get to `objects` folder from there, you  have to do

```
__dirname + "/../public/lib/objects" //from getData.js
```

Comment: I have tried this already. __dirname gives me the current folder location which is helpers.so path becomes app/helpers/public/lib/objects giving me an error. Just tried it again.

Comment: update the question with the error you got when you tried `__dirname + "/../public/lib/objects"` in getData.js file

Comment: updated the error. gives same location for both __dirname + "/public/lib/objects" and __dirname + "/../public/lib/objects"

Comment: @sushmitsarmah: dude how come? `__dirname + "/../public/lib/objects"` should work fine. there is noway that both `__dirname + "/public/lib/objects"` and `__dirname + "/../public/lib/objects"` give same location from your getData.js :)

Comment: @sushmitsarmah in the error you updated you are missing the ../ in the path

Comment: I know. Which is why I asked the question. This is exactly what I am getting. And I have been breaking my head over why this is happening

Comment: @sushmitsarmah : you just need to try `__dirname + "/../public/lib/objects"`. And update the error you got in question. Your updated error above doesnt match the folder structure or the above path i asked u to try.

Comment: Currently my alternative is putting the whole function in my app.js file. But I want it as a module as its a huge function

Comment: if you need to solve this issue, you need to update the error you get on trying `__dirname + "/../public/lib/objects"`. currently you are trying without ../

Comment: fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/../public/lib/objects"). This is what I put and the error I get is '/home/sushmitsarmah/projects/app/helpers/public/lib/objects' without the /../

Comment: your path wont have ../ in any case. But it should strip the helpers from it which is not happening. Verify the detail that you put in qn is right

Comment: and this happens only with /../    I tried /../../ and /./ and it shows up correctly

Comment: I am sorry to say you have not shared the proper folder structure here. Update the question with proper details.